# Google Drive files opening in new window vs new tab?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-drive, google-workspace-for-business

This might be a duplicate of [How to open Google Drive files in new window](https://superuser.com/questions/775653/how-to-open-google-drive-files-in-new-window) but that question is 5 years old and unanswered.

When I'm in drive.google.com and I open a G Suite file (either double-click or select & press enter) in Firefox it opens in a new window whereas in Chrome it opens in a new tab.

Why do they do that? Is this a browser-specific quirk or a Google setting (that I haven't found)? Is there a way to control the behavior? I'd like them both to open in tabs, but presumably the same answer would be relevant in the opposite direction too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...in Firefox it opens in a new window whereas in Chrome it opens in a
> new tab.
> ...**a browser-specific quirk**.

## Firefox: how to open drive.google.com files in a new tab.

- Go to `Options`-> `General`
- Find `Tabs`
- **Check** the: `Open links in tabs instead of new windows` option
- Done :)

[image: open in tabs]