# How to open Google docs in new tab in Firefox

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-docs, firefox

When I click a Gdrive item in Firefox it always opens in the current tab. How do I get it to open in another tab. When I click on any other URL it opens in a new tab why not Google docs?

In Chrome when I click on a Google drive item (such as a Gdoc or Gsheet) it will open in a new tab by default.

This is really frustrating if I'm working in a folder that is many levels deep and I open a document I have to open Gdrive again in another tab and navigate all the way back to the folder I was in to get to another document.

[It appears this was once an option Google docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19782/how-do-i-stop-google-docs-from-opening-documents-in-new-tabs), but it has now been removed...

[UPDATE] THIS IS NOT the SAME ISSUE AS OPENING IN A WINDOW VS. IN TAB

In my case it is opening IN THE SAME WINDOW.

[UPDATE 2] I have checked the option in firefox options as well as in about:config and open in new tab is selected. The behaviour works properly on other sites and apps, just not google docs and other apps. It seems that google do not display the buttons like opening a new document as a standard URL in html.

I can use  firefox's center click to open in new tab in some cases, but not all and particularly not when opening a doc.

Comment: @Tedinoz no, the question you linked is about it opening in a new window, whereas the present question is about it opening in the same tab. They're different.

Comment: When I open a Google Doc in Firefox 70.0.1 (64-bit) for Linux Mint - 1.0, it opens in a new tab.

Comment: @ahorn I linked to that question to refer to a deprecated option (the window vs. tab option no longer exists) hoping it would lead to a solution. I'm using Firefox 70.0.1 on windows 7 and I can confirm it opens in the same tab...

Comment: @Rubén can you remove the marked as duplicate...that question is not the same ...

Comment: @pointydrip Have you already look at the Firefox options described in the answer to the other question?

Comment: @pointydrip the best workaround is to duplicate the tab you're on (Google Drive), by right clicking the tab header, then clicking "duplicate tab". Then open the Doc in either one of the duplicated tabs.

Comment: @Rubén yes that option no longer exists. I've also looked at about:config but there are hundreds of options related to tabs. There is one option for open url in a new tab and that is set to true and works with other sites and apps. It's only google docs. I noticed that in some places I am able to use center click to open in a new tab, but that does not work everywhere. For example I can center click to open gdrive from within gmail, but I cannot open a document from within gdrive with center click. This leads me to believe that gdrive buttons are not seen as a 'URL' by firefox

Comment: @pointydrip that is importan to mention in the question. Please [edit] it.

Comment: To everyone. Referring to the [linked question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/133503/). **The answer still stands correct**. _"that option no longer exists"_. **The option does exist in Firefox 70.0.1 (64-bit) for both Windows and Mac**. _(Sorry I don't have Linux installed)_. It may be a Linux issue. Please share a screenshot of your Linux FireFox `Preferences` at `Options`-> `General` -> `Tabs` _" ...I cannot open a document from within gdrive with center click. ...gdrive buttons are not seen as a 'URL' by firefox"_. Partly correct. This was **never an option at any browser**.

Comment: @marikamitsos some clarification: **the option to open in a new tab in google docs no longer exists** which is what the answer in the link describes not the option in firefox. It is however supposed to be default to open in a new tab. And also **you can center click to open in a new tab** with firefox and that option is found in about:config. I can prove that it works as I use it all the time...for some reason it does not work on opening google docs.

Comment: @marikamitsos here is my firefox option: [link](https://pasteboard.co/IJz1RCg.png)

Comment: @marikamitsos this is a screen shot of the option in google docs that the post link refers to and no longer exists: [image](https://pasteboard.co/IJz2tHZ.png)

Comment: @Rubén I have edited it in the comments please remove duplicate as it is clearly not a duplicate.

Comment: @ahorn thanks for the workaround, it's a bit tedious when you work with 30+ documents in a day, but It will have to do. I wonder if it's a windows 7 thing, I thought I was going to fight the upgrade, but maybe I won't have a choice.

Comment: You lost me. You post a [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/136720/how-to-open-google-docs-in-new-tab-in-firefox?noredirect=1#comment125382_136720) and screenshots which prove exactly the points everyone else is making. Anyway. I hope you find a workable solution.

Comment: @marikamitos because it still does not work! The link is in reference to google docs options which you are confusing with firefox options in your comment. I am able to open urls in a new tab for everything except google docs even though the google behaviour is supposed to by default open in a new tab and I have the option set in firefox...still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the name and version of your operative system and what is the firefox version that you are using? Have you already tried using firefox in private mode with all the extensions disabled?

Comment: @marikamitsos don't worry about Linux. The OP is using Windows.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

1. Open about:config
2. Search for`browser.link.open_newwindow`
3. Set value to `0`
4. Restart Firefox
5. Go to options and uncheck "Open links in tabs instead of new windows"
6. Restart Firefox
7. Go to options and check "Open links in tabs instead of new windows"
8. Restart Firefox

You may be able to just set the value to "3" instead of zero, but since I am not sure what other variables are changed by checking the box so this is the guaranteed approach at this point. You may also be able to skip option 6.

Somehow it is possible for the "Open links in tabs instead of new windows" option to be checked, but not changed in about:config properly.

I'm not sure how this happened, but checking and unchecking was not changing anything while it was set to "1". 
Here is a link for the exact value behaviour: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow

Comment: Followed these steps exactly, but it did not change the original behavior of opening Google Drive files in the same tab for me in Firefox 94.0.1, Mac OS 10.15.7